# 'RegistrationTestModel has no attribute '_deferred'

Tags: django, google-app-engine, pydev

I am trying to get the Django Shell working with the Google App Engine. Unfortunately, I am getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: type object 'RegistrationTestModel' has no attribute '_deferred'
```

Does anyone have any idea of how to fix this?

Stack trace:

```
WARNING:root:Could not read datastore data from /var/folders/X0/X0QgAfs7Hd8IcCVZOIkiCE+++TI/-Tmp-/django_content-sharer.datastore
WARNING:root:Could not initialize images API; you are likely missing the Python "PIL" module. ImportError: No module named _imaging
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 30, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "/Users/chris/Documents/workspace/ContentSharer/src/__init__.py", line 362, in execute_manager    
  File "/Users/chris/Documents/workspace/ContentSharer/src/__init__.py", line 303, in execute
  File "/Users/chris/Documents/workspace/ContentSharer2/src/django/core/management/base.py", line 195, in run_from_argv
  File "/Users/chris/Documents/workspace/ContentSharer2/src/django/core/management/base.py", line 222, in execute
  File "/Users/chris/Documents/workspace/ContentSharer2/src/django/core/management/base.py", line 351, in handle
  File "/Users/chris/Documents/workspace/ContentSharer/src/django/core/management/commands/shell.py", line 18, in handle_noargs
    loaded_models = get_models()
  File "/Users/chris/Documents/workspace/ContentSharer2/src/django/db/models/loading.py", line 166, in get_models
AttributeError: type object 'RegistrationTestModel' has no attribute '_deferred'
```

Comment: We really need the entire stacktrace to be of any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Django 1.1.2 with the helper?  <strike>If so, the helper has not yet been updated for Django 1.1.2 yet.</strike>  Be sure to get r105 or later of the helper.  As a side note, Django 1.1.2 hasn't been installed on production for use_library yet, as far as I know.

<strike>Try using Django 1.1.1 until 1.1.2 is available on GAE production and the helper has been updated.</strike>

Patch is included in this ticket: http://code.google.com/p/google-app-engine-django/issues/detail?id=171

Update: the helper has been patched with r105 http://code.google.com/p/google-app-engine-django/source/detail?r=105

Comment: I've included the patch for 1.1.2 in this ticket: http://code.google.com/p/google-app-engine-django/issues/detail?id=171

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to load a part of Django that depends on Django models. Django models do not work on App Engine, as they depend on a relational database.

Try [django-nonrel](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/django-nonrel) instead.

Comment: I am just trying to get the shell working. I have no clue what `RegistrationTestModel` is. Does the shell work with Django Helper?

Comment: I believe it does, but I'm not a Django user. All I know is that the stacktrace shows it trying to import the Django models library, and that doesn't work on App Engine.